# WAMP : Setting /home/.../public_html/ in Virtual Host

Tags: php, apache, wamp

OK, so I've set up a virtual host in WAMP and it's working absolutely fine - I go to the hostname and it indeed goes to the right place, but the PHP script is trying to include a file from `/home/*hostname*/public_html/(etc...)` and failing, as it *should* be trying to include `(etc...)` directly, from the working directory.

My question is simple, yet I couldn't find anything online where someone else had the same problem, but how do I replace `/home/*hostname*/public_html/` with `/` or otherwise ensure that `/home/*hostname/public_html` will always load from a directory I specify? I tried a RewriteRule but it didn't seem to have any effect...

Here's the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file which I'm sure is where the fix needs to be applied...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAlias mysite
ServerName mysite
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/mysite/"
<Directory  "c:/wamp/www/mysite">
    AllowOverride all
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
    Require local

    #RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteRule ^/home/mysite/public_html/(.*)/$  /$1
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**EDIT:** Ok, this is new to me as it's a clients website that I've just started trying to work on, and I've figured out it is using 'OpenCart' and that there is a `config.php` file I can edit to fix this. Still, I would appreciate knowing why my attempt to bypass this wouldn't work (it will be more convenient to leave the `config.php` file un-edited).

Comment: I'm not sure about what you're talking about with those last 2 rewrite instructions... do a <?php print getcwd() ?> and show us the output.

Comment: @rotvulpix that would be `C:\wamp\www\*hostname*` - as I say, I figure it's trying to include `C:\wamp\www\*hostname*\home\*hostname*\public_html\...` as if it were a real server when it should just be including from the current dir